# Proper way to refresh Single Page Application

Tags: angular, single-page-application

I have an angular2 Single Page app. I want to prompt the user to reload the page when I have rolled a new version out to the production server.  I have heard about AppCache. I have heard about Service Workers.

What is the accepted practice for this operation?

What process do you go through to detect a change and then force the refresh?

Is there something already in the browser that supports this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to dynamically check for a new version, or simply ensure that it loads at page load? Whatever you do it should be transparent to the user. We use Grunt Cache-bust to append random strings to the JS filenames.

Comment: @isherwood I don't know if that solution actually makes the most sense. Basically, I want to detect that the application JS has changed, and then prompt the user that something has changed and invite them to refresh.  Grunt Cache-bust wouldn't help with that.

Comment: Well, you'll have to have some mechanism to indicate updated files, so cachebusting is probably still a good idea (and would guarantee current version on page load). You'd then have to poll the server to check versions periodically. Unless you have an app that users tend to keep open for days at a stretch, this seems excessive.

Comment: @isherwood Thank you for the response. I do have an app that users can leave open for days. That's the problem. Is there anything in the javascript platform, or the browser platform that supports this kind of thing?

Comment: Sure. I described one approach using cachebusting and a periodic poll of the server. I suggest that you edit your question to ask something more specific. As it is it's somewhat off-topic as too broad and opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

Idon't know if there's a standard practice, but here's how I've done it once, successfully:

When I deploy version 123, I ensure that the main index.html file contains this line:

```
<script>var MYAPP_VERSION=123;</script>
```

and that the backend sends, as a header of all the responses to AJAX requests, the header `x-myapp-version=123`.

In the application (angular1, but you can something similar with angular 2), every time I receive an AJAX response from the backend, I check that the version in the header is identical to the version in MYAPP_VERSION.

If the versions differ, that means that a new version has been deployed, but that the user is still using an old version (i.e. has not refreshed the main page). I then display an alert message or a popup (or I force a refresh), to make sure the page is refreshed. That, combined with a version of hash in the JS files and templates (or proper cache configuration, allows making sure the user gets the new versions of the files.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I thought of that, but it seems kind of heavy handed, and I was wondering if there is a defacto standard to to do this in Javascript.

Comment: Hi did you have any new thought about this question. I found I still can't find a satisfied answer. I asked my question here with new information https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/423068/options-to-notify-users-single-page-application-spa-static-resources-have-upda